# Incongruous timestamps in SMS

Tags: 8.0, sms

I was texting with my wife, and all of a sudden the time stamps didn't seem to line up right for awhile.

[image]

As you can see, it seems as if some of my responses were sent to her before she sent her texts. After this sequence, everything went along normally though.

What causes this?

Comment: I've already noticed this behavior and looks like this timestamp is somewhat provided by the carrier. But not sure.

Comment: what is solution to this problem? Does the automatical setting work or not? Thank you, Jakub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the clocks being out of sync - I've noticed that when the clock on my wife's phone is slow, they show slow on my phone, and fix as soon as I update the time on her phone.

One thing I have noticed is that the "set time automatically" [setting is rubbish](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/761/106), so you're at the mercy of drift on the clocks, or regular checking if your network doesn't support the setting of date/time automatically.

Comment: That's really strange, considering that we're on the same carrier. Granted we weren't on the same towers at the time (about 50 miles apart), but you would think we should be more in synch.

Comment: Everything I've seen implies that the "set time automatically" option doesn't *keep* the clocks in sync (at least not with my carrier, so I've gone to manual setting)

Comment: The "set time automatically" setting DOES work. However networks apparently have the wrong time. T-Mobile in the UK consistently sets my phone to 2-3 minutes ahead.