# How often does the OS sync date/time when set to do so automatically?

Tags: nokia-lumia-930

Just had to reboot my 930 for the first time ever. In Date Time options it's set to update automatically, but it's been ~10 minutes and it's still showing some date back in November. How often does it synchronise?

Comment: What exact version of Windows Phone have you installed? Did you get the Denim update yet?

Comment: Yes - I have denim. It's on the UK EE network, but is not a carrier supplied phone, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm also on EE's UK network, and it appears that [not all carriers provide network time synchronization](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/761/106), and I think EE is one of those that don't. You may be better off just setting the date/time manually

Comment: Looks like you're correct - I left it for 90 minutes and there was no sync. A restart didn't cause it to correct itself either. Might be interesting for users of other networks to experiment to see what happens.

Comment: Thats why I asked. With Denim the phone should support synchronization through Microsofts servers.

Comment: Ah, well that isn't working evidently, or is so infrequent to be unhelpful. I left it for ~140 minutes before I lost patience and set it myself. Would have thought it would be relatively easy for the OS to get the time via GPS rather than rely on a time server though.

Comment: The Denim update should be available for you, if you haven't already installed it